# Jquery add css to head

Tags: jquery, css, asynchronous, head

I am asynchronously adding a few scripts and style sheets to a project that I am building and would like to keep the style sheets all grouped together in the HEAD.

```
<head>
  <title>home</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="Shortcut Icon" type="image/ico" href="/img/favicon.png">

  <!-- STYLES-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/fonts-and-colors.css" type="text/css" media="screen"> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/layout.css" type="text/css" media="screen">

  <!-- JS-->
  <script type="text/javascript" async="" src="/js/light-box.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/grade-button.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // some code
    });
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/masterBlaster.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
</head>
```

I am currently using

```
$("head").append("<link rel='stylesheet' href='/css/masterBlaster.css' type='text/css' media='screen'>");
```

which works fine, but it adds it to the bottom of my HEAD section as you can see in the example.

The OCD in me would like to add it either before my first style link or after the last style link.

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This will place the new `link` after the last `link` already in your `head` element.

```
$("head link[rel='stylesheet']").last().after("<link rel='stylesheet' href='/css/masterBlaster.css' type='text/css' media='screen'>");
```

However if you don't already have a `link` in place this won't add the new `link`. Therefore you should do a check first:

```
var $head = $("head");
var $headlinklast = $head.find("link[rel='stylesheet']:last");
var linkElement = "<link rel='stylesheet' href='/css/masterBlaster.css' type='text/css' media='screen'>";
if ($headlinklast.length){
   $headlinklast.after(linkElement);
}
else {
   $head.append(linkElement);
}
```

---

> The OCD in me would like to add it either before my first style link
>   or after the last style link.

You should decide where exactly the `link` is going to be placed. Theres a chance a different position might override existing styles.

Comment: Good answer, looks like we answered at the same time. However, this will insert it after the last of any link element in the head, not just the last stylesheet link as requested.

Comment: @blesh Cheers, likewise your answer doesn't take in account what happens if there are no `link` elements already.

Comment: Meh, I'm deleting my answer then and removing my downvote. I'd fix a few things about yours however... I'd create the <link string in a seperate variable so it's not declared twice, and I'd also use the :last selector rather than .last(), so the selector is selecting exactly what I want, rather than making two method calls for no reason.

Comment: Also, +1 for the most complete answer.

Comment: @blesh Cheers for comments, I've made some changes so that less calls are made

Comment: your solution works great.  I modified it a bit to add the link to the begining of the style block `$headlink.first().before();`.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

you can use:

> .prepend()

http://api.jquery.com/prepend/