# Append CSS to head?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, class

I want to add some css classes in head Tag, with jQuery (and not a css file like [Jquery add css to head](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12093509/jquery-add-css-to-head))

My css classes are like this:

```
#control1 { width:60px; height:55px; background:url(../images/logo1.png) no-repeat; float:left; }
#control1.selected {background:url(../images/logo1_aktiv.png) no-repeat;}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Same thing, just replace the `link` element with a `style` one in the accepted answer..

Comment: You want to add rules to the stylesheet?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Why not add styles inline? Why not define styles before hand, and toggle them with JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is what you need to do, append your style to the head tag

```
var yourClasses="#control1 { width:60px; height:55px; background:url(../images/logo1.png) no-repeat; float:left; }
#control1.selected {background:url(../images/logo1_aktiv.png) no-repeat;}";

$("document").ready(function(){
    $("head").append("<style type='text/css'>"+yourClasses+"</style>");
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have edited it and created a variable for each css class :)

Answer (score 2):

You can append it to the head section using `appendTo()`, and then selecting `"head"`

```
$("<style type='text/css'> .boldYellow{color:yellow; font-weight:bold;} </style>").appendTo("head");
```