# Is it valid to use data:text/css?

Tags: jquery, css, html, user-experience, data-uri

I want to add (append) 3 `CSS` rules to my `head` tag using `<link />` tags

```
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="data:text/css, .rule0 {} .rule1 {} .rule2 {}" />');
```

Is this syntax valid to use or not?

I know I can wrap my rules within `<style>` Like

```
$('head').append('<style>.rule0 {} .rule1 {} .rule2 {}</style>');
```

Comment: [There you go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12093509/jquery-add-css-to-head)

Comment: You didn't get my question, I don't want to load the my CSS from a location, plus this is an UX question

Comment: you could `document.createElement('style')` and populate its content (with the styles) then append it. Otherwise, I _believe_ you can do what you're after, but it'd be more like `data:text/css;base64,....` and base64 encode it to avoid spaces and other data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you can as long as you properly declare the data URI. I've found the following to work:

```
// Your CSS content, whatever it may be
var css = '*{color:red;}';

// Build your `<link>` dynamically
var link = document.createElement('link');
link.rel = 'stylesheet';
link.href = 'data:text/css;charset=UTF-8,' + encodeURIComponent(css);

// Append to `<head>`
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
```

Results in the [page text turning red](http://jsfiddle.net/Peu4n/).

Though, depending on how long your CSS it, you may also want to base64 encode it. So, your `.href` becomes:

```
// note: you need to find a base64_encode implementation for this; javascript
//       doesn't natively have one.
link.href = 'data:text/css;base64,' + base64_encode(css);
```

Comment: +1 for the `base64` encode, and I found this tool which uses PHP to encode a string into base64 http://www.base64encode.org/ which came handy

Comment: @AnnaSkylar: keep in mind, the biggest pitfalls with using a data URI is you lose caching. Every visit sends the complete payload, so if you use it on a popular page you'll always have that overhead. But, if you're comfortable with that then it's fine with me. ;-)

Comment: it's only 3 rules of CSS and the `.css` is 0.19 KB, it won't cause problems for slow connections