# Programmatically added Stylesheet Element not being honored by dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In our web app, I'm trying to hit our server to determine if they have made any custom CSS tweaks to the layout of the web app. Upon getting a boolean flag of this, I'm returning the CSS from the server and injecting a new `head link` after the last one...

The problem is, this isn't updating the page's style or layout. If I go into the sources of the page elements and click on that CSS document in the dev console, I can force it to "notice" that this css is available by simply changing the value of a style reference.

**This is the jquery I'm using to inject the CSS**:

```
$("head link[rel='stylesheet']").last().after("<link rel='stylesheet' href='4DACTION/WEB_Mobile_CustomCSS' type='text/css' media='screen'>");
```

Any idea why it wouldn't force the page to use it until I've made a change to it in the debugger?

Comment: This may not have anything to do with anything... but is it the same in more than one browser?

Comment: Well, doesn't it have to fire an HTTP request after you make this change in order for it to be "noticed"?

Comment: Another idea, you could just use Document.write() to write any CSS (not the link, but CSS itself) and it wouldn't fire an extra HTTP request in this way.

Comment: Can you give a reason not to, adeneo? I'm sure we could all learn from you.

Comment: What do you mean by *I'm returning the CSS from the server*?

Comment: First of all, do you have other stylesheets, otherwise `last()` won't find anything. Secondly `4DACTION/WEB_Mobile_CustomCSS` doesn't look like a valid URL to a stylesheet ?

Comment: @Feign - Just search for `document.write` and `bad idea` or something similar, and you'll figure it out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery add css to head](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12093509/jquery-add-css-to-head)

Comment: I've noticed this issue in Chrome before on our site but never had a chance to pin point the cause. As @gloomy.penguin suggested, have you tried to see if the same issue occurs in other browsers?

Also, can you specify which particular style declarations are not having an effect?

Comment: @adeneo Yes, there will always be a couple of other stylesheets present. The reason for the odd request name is because this is a 4D Database. That's a method call to the DB that returns the respective document. In this case it's a large list of CSS declarations.

Comment: @gearsdigital I'm not asking how to do it (As that thread states) but why it's not performing as expected. I already have it showing up in my head.
..HaykoKoryun I've tested it in Safari and it doesn't work there either.

Answer (score 0):

I used Bootstrap to create an example doing exactly what you described using your code in a `setTimeout` callback:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $("head link[rel='stylesheet']").last().after("<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css' type='text/css' media='screen'>");
}, 1000);
```

check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/v089p29a/ it switches from flat buttons to 3D ones.

I'm not sure why this is not working for you. Maybe your URL is not valid like [adeneo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965051/adeneo) suggested. Also be sure to put your code in the `$(window).load()` or `$(document).ready()` event handlers to ensure that the DOM is ready to be manipulated.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up just sending back plain text and injecting it into a `style` tag in the `head`... Not sure why my stylesheet method wasn't working.